# Import UTF-8 file in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'd like to import a pipe delimited file in a table but this file is in UTF-8 with dynamic structure.

I had tried with TranfertText and FSO but only ADODB.Stream seems to deal well with such an encoding however it only read the full text...

How can I read such a file line per line to add rows in an existing table ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try transfertext with a code page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx  or filesystemobject with tristate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59(v=vs.84).aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a line from an ADO Stream with its [ReadText](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_stream_readtext.asp) method.

```
strLine = objStream.ReadText -2 ' adReadLine
```

You may need to set your stream's [LineSeparator](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_stream_lineseparator.asp) property first.

After you read the line, you can split on the pipe character.

```
Split(strLine, "|")
```