# Parse simple two dimensional JSON array in VBA without external libraries

Tags: arrays, json, vba

I have decoded a simple two-dimensional array in JavaScript into a JSON and need to parse it in VBA. The json looks something like this:

```
[
  [
    "String1",
    "Sring2"
  ],
  [
    "String3",
    "String4"
  ]
]
```

There are always 2 Strings in each array.

Answer (score 1):

The below example shows how to parse JSON and convert to array. Put the below code into VBA Project standard module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestToArray()

    ' Put source JSON string to "\source.json" file
    ' Processed table will be placed on the first worksheet

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    sJSONString = ReadTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\source.json", -2)
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        If UBound(aHeader) >= 0 Then OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                1, _
                UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath As String, lFormat As Long) As String
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sContent As String, sPath As String, lFormat As Long)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, lFormat)
        .Write (sContent)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Create one more standard module, name it `JSON` and put the below code into it, this code provides JSON processing functionality:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private sBuffer As String
Private oTokens As Object
Private oRegEx As Object
Private bMatch As Boolean
Private oChunks As Object
Private oHeader As Object
Private aData() As Variant
Private i As Long

Sub Parse(ByVal sSample As String, vJSON As Variant, sState As String)

    ' Backus–Naur form JSON parser implementation based on RegEx
    ' Input:
    ' sSample - source JSON string
    ' Output:
    ' vJson - created object or array to be returned as result
    ' sState - string Object|Array|Error depending on processing

    sBuffer = sSample
    Set oTokens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oRegEx ' Patterns based on specification http://www.json.org/
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True ' Unspecified True, False, Null accepted
        .Pattern = "(?:'[^']*'|""(?:\\""|[^""])*"")(?=\s*[,\:\]\}])" ' Double-quoted string, unspecified quoted string
        Tokenize "s"
        .Pattern = "[+-]?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?(?=\s*[,\]\}])" ' Number, E notation number
        Tokenize "d"
        .Pattern = "\b(?:true|false|null)(?=\s*[,\]\}])" ' Constants true, false, null
        Tokenize "c"
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=\s*\:)" ' Unspecified non-double-quoted property name accepted
        Tokenize "n"
        .Pattern = "\s+"
        sBuffer = .Replace(sBuffer, "") ' Remove unnecessary spaces
        .MultiLine = False
        Do
            bMatch = False
            .Pattern = "<\d+(?:[sn])>\:<\d+[codas]>" ' Object property structure
            Tokenize "p"
            .Pattern = "\{(?:<\d+p>(?:,<\d+p>)*)?\}" ' Object structure
            Tokenize "o"
            .Pattern = "\[(?:<\d+[codas]>(?:,<\d+[codas]>)*)?\]" ' Array structure
            Tokenize "a"
        Loop While bMatch
        .Pattern = "^<\d+[oa]>$" ' Top level object structure, unspecified array accepted
        If .Test(sBuffer) And oTokens.Exists(sBuffer) Then
            Retrieve sBuffer, vJSON
            sState = IIf(IsObject(vJSON), "Object", "Array")
        Else
            vJSON = Null
            sState = "Error"
        End If
    End With
    Set oTokens = Nothing
    Set oRegEx = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Tokenize(sType)

    Dim aContent() As String
    Dim lCopyIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sKey As String

    With oRegEx.Execute(sBuffer)
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        ReDim aContent(0 To .Count - 1)
        lCopyIndex = 1
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1
            With .Item(i)
                sKey = "<" & oTokens.Count & sType & ">"
                oTokens(sKey) = .Value
                aContent(i) = Mid(sBuffer, lCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lCopyIndex + 1) & sKey
                lCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
            End With
        Next
    End With
    sBuffer = Join(aContent, "") & Mid(sBuffer, lCopyIndex, Len(sBuffer) - lCopyIndex + 1)
    bMatch = True

End Sub

Private Sub Retrieve(sTokenKey, vTransfer)

    Dim sTokenValue As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim aTokens() As String
    Dim i As Long

    sTokenValue = oTokens(sTokenKey)
    With oRegEx
        .Global = True
        Select Case Left(Right(sTokenKey, 2), 1)
            Case "o"
                Set vTransfer = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<")
                For i = 1 To UBound(aTokens)
                    Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(i), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vTransfer
                Next
            Case "p"
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<", 4)
                Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(1), ">", 2)(0) & ">", sName
                Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(2), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vValue
                If IsObject(vValue) Then
                    Set vTransfer(sName) = vValue
                Else
                    vTransfer(sName) = vValue
                End If
            Case "a"
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<")
                If UBound(aTokens) = 0 Then
                    vTransfer = Array()
                Else
                    ReDim vTransfer(0 To UBound(aTokens) - 1)
                    For i = 1 To UBound(aTokens)
                        Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(i), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vValue
                        If IsObject(vValue) Then
                            Set vTransfer(i - 1) = vValue
                        Else
                            vTransfer(i - 1) = vValue
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Case "n"
                vTransfer = sTokenValue
            Case "s"
                vTransfer = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Mid(sTokenValue, 2, Len(sTokenValue) - 2), _
                    "\""", """"), _
                    "\\", "\"), _
                    "\/", "/"), _
                    "\b", Chr(8)), _
                    "\f", Chr(12)), _
                    "\n", vbLf), _
                    "\r", vbCr), _
                    "\t", vbTab)
                .Global = False
                .Pattern = "\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
                Do While .Test(vTransfer)
                    vTransfer = .Replace(vTransfer, ChrW(("&H" & Right(.Execute(vTransfer)(0).Value, 4)) * 1))
                Loop
            Case "d"
                vTransfer = Evaluate(sTokenValue)
            Case "c"
                Select Case LCase(sTokenValue)
                    Case "true"
                        vTransfer = True
                    Case "false"
                        vTransfer = False
                    Case "null"
                        vTransfer = Null
                End Select
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Function Serialize(vJSON As Variant) As String

    Set oChunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    SerializeElement vJSON, ""
    Serialize = Join(oChunks.Items(), "")
    Set oChunks = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub SerializeElement(vElement As Variant, ByVal sIndent As String)

    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With oChunks
        Select Case VarType(vElement)
            Case vbObject
                If vElement.Count = 0 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "{}"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = "{" & vbCrLf
                    aKeys = vElement.Keys
                    For i = 0 To UBound(aKeys)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & vbTab & """" & aKeys(i) & """" & ": "
                        SerializeElement vElement(aKeys(i)), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(aKeys)) Then .Item(.Count) = ","
                        .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                    .Item(.Count) = sIndent & "}"
                End If
            Case Is >= vbArray
                If UBound(vElement) = -1 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "[]"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = "[" & vbCrLf
                    For i = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & vbTab
                        SerializeElement vElement(i), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(vElement)) Then .Item(.Count) = "," 'sResult = sResult & ","
                        .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                    .Item(.Count) = sIndent & "]"
                End If
            Case vbInteger, vbLong
                .Item(.Count) = vElement
            Case vbSingle, vbDouble
                .Item(.Count) = Replace(vElement, ",", ".")
            Case vbNull
                .Item(.Count) = "null"
            Case vbBoolean
                .Item(.Count) = IIf(vElement, "true", "false")
            Case Else
                .Item(.Count) = """" & _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(vElement, _
                        "\", "\\"), _
                        """", "\"""), _
                        "/", "\/"), _
                        Chr(8), "\b"), _
                        Chr(12), "\f"), _
                        vbLf, "\n"), _
                        vbCr, "\r"), _
                        vbTab, "\t") & _
                    """"
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Function ToString(vJSON As Variant) As String

    Select Case VarType(vJSON)
        Case vbObject, Is >= vbArray
            Set oChunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            ToStringElement vJSON, ""
            oChunks.Remove 0
            ToString = Join(oChunks.Items(), "")
            Set oChunks = Nothing
        Case vbNull
            ToString = "Null"
        Case vbBoolean
            ToString = IIf(vJSON, "True", "False")
        Case Else
            ToString = CStr(vJSON)
    End Select

End Function

Private Sub ToStringElement(vElement As Variant, ByVal sIndent As String)

    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With oChunks
        Select Case VarType(vElement)
            Case vbObject
                If vElement.Count = 0 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "''"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    aKeys = vElement.Keys
                    For i = 0 To UBound(aKeys)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & aKeys(i) & ": "
                        ToStringElement vElement(aKeys(i)), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(aKeys)) Then .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                End If
            Case Is >= vbArray
                If UBound(vElement) = -1 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "''"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    For i = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & i & ": "
                        ToStringElement vElement(i), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(vElement)) Then .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                End If
            Case vbNull
                .Item(.Count) = "Null"
            Case vbBoolean
                .Item(.Count) = IIf(vElement, "True", "False")
            Case Else
                .Item(.Count) = CStr(vElement)
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Sub ToArray(vJSON As Variant, aRows() As Variant, aHeader() As Variant)

    ' Input:
    ' vJSON - Array or Object which contains rows data
    ' Output:
    ' aData - 2d array representing JSON data
    ' aHeader - 1d array of property names

    Dim sName As Variant

    Set oHeader = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Select Case VarType(vJSON)
        Case vbObject
            If vJSON.Count > 0 Then
                ReDim aData(0 To vJSON.Count - 1, 0 To 0)
                oHeader("#") = 0
                i = 0
                For Each sName In vJSON
                    aData(i, 0) = "#" & sName
                    ToArrayElement vJSON(sName), ""
                    i = i + 1
                Next
            Else
                ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            End If
        Case Is >= vbArray
            If UBound(vJSON) >= 0 Then
                ReDim aData(0 To UBound(vJSON), 0 To 0)
                For i = 0 To UBound(vJSON)
                    ToArrayElement vJSON(i), ""
                Next
            Else
                ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            End If
        Case Else
            ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            aData(0, 0) = ToString(vJSON)
    End Select
    aHeader = oHeader.Keys()
    Set oHeader = Nothing
    aRows = aData
    Erase aData

End Sub

Private Sub ToArrayElement(vElement As Variant, sFieldName As String)

    Dim sName As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    Select Case VarType(vElement)
        Case vbObject ' collection of objects
            For Each sName In vElement
                ToArrayElement vElement(sName), sFieldName & IIf(sFieldName = "", "", "_") & sName
            Next
        Case Is >= vbArray  ' collection of arrays
            For j = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                ToArrayElement vElement(j), sFieldName & IIf(sFieldName = "", "", "_") & "#" & j
            Next
        Case Else
            If Not oHeader.Exists(sFieldName) Then
                oHeader(sFieldName) = oHeader.Count
                If UBound(aData, 2) < oHeader.Count - 1 Then ReDim Preserve aData(0 To UBound(aData, 1), 0 To oHeader.Count - 1)
            End If
            j = oHeader(sFieldName)
            aData(i, j) = ToString(vElement)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Paste your JSON string to text file and save it as `source.json` in ANSI or Unicode to the same folder as the workbook, then run `TestToArray()`. If you add breakpoint at the end of the sub, you will see the variables in locals window as follows:

[image: locals]

As you can see there are `vJSON` which represents the JSON structure - actually it consists of nested 1d-arrays, and 2d-array `aData`. So you can choose which array to use.

**Check [VBA-JSON-parser on GitHub](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) for the latest version of JSON parser (import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser/blob/master/JSON.bas) module into the VBA project for JSON processing).**

Comment: Might run into trouble with the file's character encoding. As [JSON](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1) is one of  UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, only UTF-16 (sometimes called "Unicode" [sic]) is compatible with this code. Of course, with extra code, it's easy to distinguish. "ADODB.Stream" is sometimes used when flexibility with character encodings is needed. ([Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201419/2226988))

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by parsing an array but may be the following could help you:

```
Sub arrays()
    Dim arr As Variant, arrElem As Variant, elem As Variant

    arr = Array(Array("String1", "String2"), _
                Array("String3", "String4")) '<--| this is what I think could be your array of arrays like

    For Each arrElem In arr '<--| loop through each array elements
        For Each elem In arrElem '<--| loop through each array element elements
            Debug.Print elem '<--| print each element
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

and this is the result in Immediate Window:

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
```

Comment: I need to parse the JSON to use the array in VBA.